# How can I get a value from other dataframe's column based on other index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Take this dataframe `df` fragment:

```
  col_1 col_2 col_3
0   aaa   !!!   sss
1   bbb   @@@   jjj
2   ccc   !!!   NaN
3   ddd   $$$   nnn
4   eee   %%%   xxx
```

I need to run a `fillna()` on `col_3` to get the value of `col_1` based on the first occurrence of the value of `col_2`.

To get it simple, this `NaN` value should by filled with `aaa`. It needs to be dynamic for the whole dataframe, and run for the whole `col_3`.

Comment: Are you saying, for each value in `col_3` with a `NaN`, check the value of `col_2` and based on the value in `col_2`, find the first occurrence and fill `col_3` with the value in `col_1` ?

Comment: Yes. Just to reinforce. 

For each value in col_3 with a NaN, check the value of col_2 in the same row, and based on the value in col_2, find the first occurrence and fill col_3 with the value in col_1.

Comment: checkout the answer. Let me know if this is what you intended from the question. I think I got it. If there are any additional conditions, we can fix them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to get this done:

- Step 1: Do a Groupby of `col_2` and find the values of `col_1` but
  pick only the first entry of this value
- Step 2: Convert this into a dictionary Both of these steps can be
  accomplished by doing:

  `df.groupby('col_2')['col_1'].first().to_dict()`
- Step 3: Now do a fillna for `col_3` using a lookup of value in
  `col_2` but mapping it back to a dictionary. So the value in `col_2`
  will be checked against the dictionary. The key would return a value.
  This value will be assigned back to `col_3`.

Putting all this together, the full code is as shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
c = ['col_1','col_2','col_3']
d = [['aaa','!!!','sss'],
['bbb','@@@','jjj'],
['ccc','!!!',np.NaN],
['ddd','$$$','nnn'],
['eee','%%%','xxx'],
['fff','@@@',np.NaN],
['ggg','$$$',np.NaN],
['hhh','%%%',np.NaN]]
df = pd.DataFrame(d,columns=c)
print (df)
dx = df.groupby('col_2')['col_1'].first().to_dict()
df['col_3'] = df.col_3.fillna(df.col_2.map(dx))
print (df)
```

Output of this will be:

**Original Dataframe:**

```
  col_1 col_2 col_3
0   aaa   !!!   sss
1   bbb   @@@   jjj
2   ccc   !!!   NaN
3   ddd   $$$   nnn
4   eee   %%%   xxx
5   fff   @@@   NaN
6   ggg   $$$   NaN
7   hhh   %%%   NaN
```

**Updated DataFrame:**

```
  col_1 col_2 col_3
0   aaa   !!!   sss
1   bbb   @@@   jjj
2   ccc   !!!   aaa
3   ddd   $$$   nnn
4   eee   %%%   xxx
5   fff   @@@   bbb
6   ggg   $$$   ddd
7   hhh   %%%   eee
```

Added more records and tested:

Original:

```
   col_1 col_2 col_3
0    aaa   !!!   sss
1    bbb   @@@   jjj
2    ccc   !!!   NaN
3    ddd   $$$   nnn
4    eee   %%%   xxx
5    fff   @@@   NaN
6    ggg   $$$   NaN
7    hhh   %%%   NaN
8    iii   !!!   NaN
9    jjj   $$$   NaN
10   kkk   &&&   ttt
```

Updated:

```
   col_1 col_2 col_3
0    aaa   !!!   sss
1    bbb   @@@   jjj
2    ccc   !!!   aaa
3    ddd   $$$   nnn
4    eee   %%%   xxx
5    fff   @@@   bbb
6    ggg   $$$   ddd
7    hhh   %%%   eee
8    iii   !!!   aaa
9    jjj   $$$   ddd
10   kkk   &&&   ttt
```